# Swipe Gesture to Specific limit

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I need to implement the swipe gesture to specific limit.
I tried using the below code

```
UIView *viewLeftSwipe = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 100, 50)];
viewLeftSwipe.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
viewLeftSwipe.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:viewLeftSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[viewLeftSwipe  addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

But it is not calling the below method

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
 NSLog(@"Swipe");
}
```

Comment: Are you swiping the `viewLeftSwipe` or some other where?

Comment: yes when the viewLeftSwupe is swiped i want to peform some action

Comment: I tried your code and it's working fine as handleSwipe: method is getting called when swipe(direction - left) is performed. So what exactly your looking for?